# Strange behavior with pandas timestamp to posix conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I do the following operations:

1. Convert string datetime in pandas dataframe to python datetime via `apply(strptime)`
2. Convert `datetime` to posix timestamp via `.timestamp()` method
3. If I revert posix back to `datetime` with `.fromtimestamp()` I obtain different datetime

It differs by 3 hours which is my timezone (I'm at UTC+3 now), so I suppose it is a kind of timezone issue. Also I understand that in apply it implicitly converts to `pandas.Timestamp`, but I don't understand the difference in this case.

What is the reason for such strange behavior and what should I do to avoid it? Actually in my project I need to compare this pandas timestamps with correct poxis timestamps and now it works wrong.

Below is dummy reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['2018-03-03 14:30:00'], columns=['c'])
df['c'] = df['c'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
dt = df['c'].iloc[0]
dt
>> Timestamp('2018-03-03 14:30:00')
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp())
>> datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 17, 30)
```

Comment: If working with dates and pandas, it's suggested to use the `np.timedelta64` functionality with `pd.to_datetime`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest using the `np.timedelta64` dtype when working with `pandas`. In this case it makes the reciprocity simple.

```
pd.to_datetime('2018-03-03 14:30:00').value
#1520087400000000000

pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime('2018-03-03 14:30:00').value)
#Timestamp('2018-03-03 14:30:00')
```

The issue with the other methods is that POSIX has UTC as the origin, but `fromtimestamp` returns the local time. If your system isn't UTC compliant, then we get issues. The following methods will work to remedy this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

dt
#Timestamp('2018-03-03 14:30:00')

# Seemingly problematic:
datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp())
#datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 9, 30)
```

---

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp(), tz=pytz.utc)
#datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 14, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>)

datetime.combine(dt.date(), dt.timetz())
#datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 14, 30)

mytz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')  # Use your own local timezone
datetime.fromtimestamp(mytz.localize(dt).timestamp())
#datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 3, 14, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer with the [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['2018-03-03 14:30:00'], columns=['c'])
df['c'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c'].values, dayfirst=False).tz_localize('Your/Timezone')
```

When working with date, you should always put a timezone it is easier after to work with.

It does not explain the difference between the `datetime` in pandas and alone.